# Import dataset to predict new data

Tags: r, import

I'm new to the R. I would like to import dataset from : https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/processed.hungarian.data. How can I do?
these are my attempts

```
# first attempt
x <- read.table("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/processed.hungarian.data")
Error in file(file, "r") : unable to open connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "r") : unsupported URL scheme

# second attempt
x <- read.table("C:/Users/Thanushiya/Desktop/processed.hungarian.data.txt", header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names="id")
Error in data[[rowvar]] : attempt to select less than one element
```

Comment: You can start reading [how to import data in R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html)

Comment: Did you try anything? Did you get an error? We assume you've at least made some effort to attempt to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: > mydata <-read.table("C:/Users/Thanushiya/Desktop/processed.switzerland.data, header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names="id")
Error: unexpected symbol in "mydata <-read.table("C:/Users/Thanushiya/Desktop/processed.switzerland.data, header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names="id"

Comment: Just drop the `s` in `https`. `read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/processed.hungarian.data", sep=",")` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Read it in a data frame (add a `sep = ","`)

```
df <- read.table("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/processed.hungarian.data",sep = ",")
```

Comment: Error in file(file, "r") : unable to open connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "r") : unsupported URL scheme

Comment: Try out using different network connection. May be your network is not allowing the R to connect to that site.
Or you can copy paste the sites data in notepad and Save it. Then again import that particular text file into your R

Comment: instad of https i try http..i t works fine.thank you